# Binding Variables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, embedded-sql

I read this script that assigns of a data column info into 2 binding variables.

something like this:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT 
var1
into :v.v1:v2
from table
```

Shouldn't there be a comma in there? Or is this like assigning `var1` into `v.v1` and also into `v2` with the same values?

Comment: Please show the lines where v, v1 and v2 are defined.

Comment: Hi Gary, sorry for the late reply. Apparently that's all i got. There's no definition for v1 or v2. Ignore the v it is just a data struct.

Answer (score 0):

The above script would give error only. if you want to assign value comma is required for the same.

The syntax would be :- Ex if you want to fetch Empno,Ename,Deptno,salary from
    EMPLOYEES.The plsql block would be as given below.

```
DECLARE

 L_EMPNO NUMBER;

 L_ENAME VARCHAR2(1000);

 L_DEPTNO NUMBER;

 L_SALARY NUMBER;

BEGIN

 SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, DEPTNO, SALARY

 INTO  L_EMPNO, L_ENAME, L_DEPTNO, L_SALARY

 FROM EMPLOYEES 

 WHERE EMPNO=100;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a snippet from a PRO*C program, a C program with embedded SQL.

v2 is an indicator variable.  See here for info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_04dat.htm#i12463

An indicator variable will contain a value that relates to it's associated variable which in this case is v.v1 and is set after the operation in which it is used.  In this case, after the select, you can test v2 and based on it's value it will tell you info about v.v1:

From the link above, if v2 equals:

```
 0  - The operation was successful
-1  - A NULL was returned, inserted, or updated.
-2  - Output to a character host variable from a "long" type was truncated, but the original column length cannot be determined.
>0  - The result of a SELECT or FETCH into a character host variable was truncated. In this case, if the host variable is a multibyte character variable, the indicator value is the original column length in characters. If the host variable is not a multibye character variable, then the indicator length is the original column length in bytes.
```

I would suggest using it's other form, which would make things clear for the person that will maintain this after you (at least do that person a favor and comment this when you get your head around it).  Always code for the person that will maintain after you.  Don't you wish the person before you did that?!:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT 
var1
into :v.v1 INDICATOR :v2
from table
```